# How to find errors in code that runs but doesn't do anything

Tags: python-3.x

Writing a short file editor following along with LPTHW on ex. 16.
When run, the script triggers no error messages but does not alter the target doc.

I've tried creating different txt files for testing, this is a persistent problem so I assume its somewhere in my code.

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print(f"We're going to erase {filename}.")
print("If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C).")
print("If you do want that, hit RETURN.")

input("?")

print("Opening the file...")
target = open(filename, 'w')

print("Truncating the file.  Goodbye!")
target.truncate()

print("Now I'm going to ask you for three lines.")

line1 = input("line 1: ")
line2 = input("line 2: ")
line3 = input("line 3: ")

print("I'm going to write these to the file.")

target.write(f"{line1}\n{line2}\n{line3}")

print("And finally, we close it.")
target.close()
print(filename)
```

The purpose of this script is open an already-existing text file, empty it, and replace the contents with the inputs of ~line1~, ~line2~ and ~line3~.

I should be able to open the file through File Explorer and observe the changes that have taken place. What is happening instead is that the script will run without errors, and when I open the text file, the changes ordered through the script have not occurred.

Comment: Are you passing the full path of the file to the script?

Comment: As a follow up to the above comment, check the folder of your script if a new file is created after you run it

Comment: I'm not passing the full file path to the script. The script is in the same folder as the target doc. The script has not been creating a new file.